# If statement won't catch a string in perl

Tags: perl, string-comparison

I'm trying to get my if statement to catch when a person enters an input that says quit or exit but it isn't. Here is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $g=0;
my $rn = int(rand(25));
until ($g == $rn) {
      $g = <STDIN>;
      if ($g == $rn) {
            print "You got it";
            } elsif (chomp($g) eq "quit" || chomp($g) eq "exit") {
            print "it triggered";
            } elsif ($g > $rn) { 
            print "incorrect its lower";
            } elsif ($g <$rn) {
            print "incorrect its higher";
            } else {
            print "end";
            }      
}
}
```

The

```
elsif (chomp($g) eq "quit" || chomp($g) eq "exit) {
```

line is not catching despite numerous attempts to catch the error. I've tried printing off what the program is seeing to no avail. What I get in response when I type in quit from the strict/warnings is that

```
argument "quit\n" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./program24.pl line 30, <STDIN> line 1.
argument "quit" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at ./program24.pl line 36, line 1.
```

I've looked at several of the other posts on this but nothing from them seems to be whats causing this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `chomp` doesn't return the chomped string; it modifies its argument in place. 2) Do the string comparison before the numerical comparison. 3) You don't handle EOF (`!defined($g)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chomp` command removes the trailing newline, but acts on the variable itself, its return value is the number of characters removed.  So typically, one only needs to `chomp` a variable or an expression once.   Since there are 2-types of comparison operators in perl, `< <= == != >= >` for numbers, `lt le eq ne ge gt` for strings, we should determine what kind of value we have before performing the comparison to avoid triggering a warning.

The `$guess =~ m|^\d+$|` statement returns true if `$guess` is a positive integer or 0, by checking that the stringified version of `$guess` is only made up of digits.

Since `rand` returns a decimal `0 <= x < 1` then `rand 25` will return a number 
`0 <= x < 25` so `25` will never be reached.  `int` will round the number down towards zero, so `int rand 25` will return one of `(0,1,2,...,22,23,24)`.  To get `(1,2,...,25)` we need to add `1`.

Single letter variables like `$g` are generally a bad idea, as they do not convey the meaning of the variable and make it more difficult to rename later if it becomes prevalent in the code.  I have replaced it with `$guess`.  In perl, the only generally accepted single letter variables are `$a` and `$b` which are global and used for comparison functions, and the perl predefined variables like `$_`, `$@`, etc. which are documented in [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $guess = 0;
my $int_max = 25;
my $rn = int(rand($int_max)) + 1;

print "I have picked a number between 1 and $int_max, can you guess it?\n";
until ($guess == $rn) {
    chomp ($guess = <STDIN>);
    if ( $guess =~ m|^\d+$| ) {
        # Answer is an integer
        if ( $guess == $rn ) {
            print "You got it!\n";
        } elsif ( $guess > $rn ) {
            print "Too high, try again.\n";
        } elsif ( $guess < $rn ) {
            print "Too low, try again.\n";
        }
    } else {
        # Anything else
        if ('quit' eq $guess or 'exit' eq $guess) {
            print "Exiting...\n";
            exit 0;
        } else {
            print "Unclear answer : '$guess' : try again!\n";
            $guess = 0; # So the equality test does not warn
        }
    }
}
```